# I am trying to validate a string with a regular expression in the javascript controller?

Tags: javascript, regex, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to validate a string with regex. that the string should contain only the listed words and characters.

(i.e) the string can accept and, or, not, numbers, (,) and blankspace.

I tried with a regular expression but its not working as expected.

```
/(\d|and|or|not|\(|\)|\s)*/
```

when i am using this in salesforce lightning component `controller.js` its is not providing the expexted result.

```
input : 1 and ( 2 or 3 )
expected output : true

input : 1 aaa ( 2 or 3 )
expected output : false
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those scenarios always in that format or are there multiple variations like `1 and ( 2 or 3 ) and (5 and 6)`

Comment: yes multiple variants can be there but the string should contain that keywords only.

Comment: Is there a pattern in those variations? Perhaps split on a space and detect if there are other words in the array?

Comment: no there is not any pattern for that. if a string is given as input the characters and word in the string should be the characters and word specified in the regular expression.   i am enforcing the string that it should contain only ( , and , or , not ,), blankspace. other than that if anything is present is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've define that you need *any* number of these and you don't care about the position. So the string `1 aaa ( 2 or 3 )` matches `1`, as well as  (space), `(`, `2`, `and`, `3`, `)` therefore it satisfies the regex. The fact that there is `aaa` which doesn't match is ignored when there are other things that do match.

However, if you use the [start and end anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` and `$`, that defines that your *entire* input must conform to this pattern as opposed to any sub-portion of it, which is exactly what you want:

```js
const regex = /^(\d|and|or|not|\(|\)|\s)*$/;

console.log(regex.test("1 and ( 2 or 3 )")); // true
console.log(regex.test("1 aaa ( 2 or 3 )")); // false
```